How to disable logging in jline3?
I need to disable logging there
I tried creating logback.xml

<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -- %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="io.netty" level="INFO"/>
</configuration>

which gave no result
I have found 0 info about jline logging in google
I also found this, but have no idea what does it mean
Change From: exec "$JAVA" -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions -jar "$AS_INSTALL_LIB/client/appserver-cli.jar" "$@"

To: exec "$JAVA" -Dfish.payara.admin.command.jline.log.disable=true -jar "$AS_INSTALL_LIB/client/appserver-cli.jar" "$@"


Did you tried  instead of ?

@AvinashGupta ye, no result
